# How to fix OutofMemoryError: Java heap space on Lubuntu?

Tags: java

I keep getting this error:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

Is there a way to fix this, I never had this problem running the same thing on Ubuntu but once I got Lubuntu this keeps occurring. Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the issue is Lubuntu, you can try this link and see if it helps.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1596009/java-lang-outofmemoryerror-java-heap-space